# addEventListener does not work on init (IE)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an EventListener on the body tag, which works fine on Chrome, but not on Internet Explorer (Edge). See code below. However, it works in IE, but *only after I select an input textbox*. But I don't want to select an input textbox first, the EventListener should listen immediately after I load the page.. What am I doing wrong here?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('paste', function() {
     console.log('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known limitation of Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard). It:

> Only fires copy event on a valid selection and only cut and paste in focused editable fields.

You are doing nothing wrong.

Since you haven't focused an element (e.g. with `autofocus`), no editable field will have the focus just after the document has loaded.

Keep in mind that IE11 is not a browser under active development. It continues to exist primarily for compatibility with ancient Intranet applications. Not with modern web applications.